# Decrement value by javascript variable inside the css property

Tags: javascript, variables, operators, jquery-animate, decrement

I wanna move content with animation.
There's an animation in the jquery function, like that:

```
.on('click', '.btn', function () {
  var contentWidth = $(window).width() - $('.sidebar').width();
  $( ".content" ).animate({
      left: "+=1000",
    }, 5000, function() {
      // moving content function
    }
  );
});
```

So, because I have various positions of content, I need to use this value in the variable contentWidth. How I can set this value in a variable and decrement the left value every time when I call a function?
Something like `left: "+=contentWidth"` doesn't work. Is where I make mistake?

Comment: I cannot use a fixed value like 1000, because, this value is permanently changing depending on the window width. So I need to calculate it, set in variable and then decrement. Something like, left: "+=contentWidth", but it doesn't work. Avoid using integer values in your answer, please. Thank you in advance! Probably, I formulated it unclear, firstly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if i got it but...

maybe you could use string interpolation

```
.on('click', '.btn', function () {
   var contentWidth = $(window).width() - $('.sidebar').width();
     $( ".content" ).animate({
       left: `+=${contentWith}`,
     }, 5000, function() {
     // moving content function
   }
 );
```

});

Not tested but should work theoretically

Comment: everything works, thank you